# Single line command to iterate & find over multiple items and update Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am wondering if there is specific query line to iterate over mongodb and update? 
For example, 
i have data with `'{"name": "A", "age": 23} .... {"name":"Z", "age":25}'` as such,

I want to iterate over with a list of names = `[A,B,C,D]`
and a list of ages = `[30,40,25,23]`.

I was thinking about for

`for(var i in names){
people.findoneandupdate("name": names[i], {$set:{"age":ages[i]}})`

is there single line query to solve this?

Comment: use mongodb transactions  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Comment: also use: `update` instead of `findoneandupdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update multiple docs in one query you can go with this:

```
Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
```

Here if you put options = { multi: true } then it will update multiple doc according to given condition